# In iOS, how to convert a web image into a less-quality one?

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

The app downloads images from the web and shows them in a table view as thumbnails. However, the quality of these image are "too good". They are HD quality and if there are too many images in a table view, it might slow down the UI a bit.

Before I set the image to a cell, how to make it "less quality"? (occupying less memory & requiring less processing power to show them)

I tried something like this:

```
let smallerImage = UIImage(CGImage: image.CGImage!, scale: 0.2, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
```

but it's not working as expected. What's the right way to do it?

Comment: You should first try to download images that are more appropriate to the display size, otherwise you'll waste the user's cell data.

Comment: @jtbandes The images downloaded are not arranged by me. They are as they are, and I want to render the images, please.

Comment: Down sampling will use more CPU resources than displaying higher resolution images

Comment: @MarkBourke Thanks for the comment. But how about the memory, maybe I need to find a balance? or simply use the high-resolution images?

Comment: It really depends how big the image is.  If it is above 2k*2k then you should resize but other than that, iOS does a pretty good job at memory management for you. NSHipster has a great guide on using the new Accelerate Framework which would probably be ur best bet being amongst the fastest and less CPU bound of all the methods.  http://nshipster.com/image-resizing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my working code from an old project from before the Swift era. An extra parameter maxLength passes the maximum height and width to use (for portrait it's max height, for landscape it's max width). Hope you know how to translate from Ojbective-C to Swift:

```
- (UIImage *) scaleImage: (UIImage *) image toMax: (float) maxLength
{
    //scale down image to fit withing square of maxLength x maxLength
    CGSize size = image.size;
    printf("scaleImage source size: %f, %f\n", size.width, size.height);
    float scaleX = size.width / maxLength;
    float scaleY = size.height / maxLength;
    float scale = scaleX > scaleY ? scaleX : scaleY;
    int newWidth = round(size.width / scale);
    int newHeight = round(size.height / scale);
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(size.width / scale, size.height / scale);
    printf("scaleImage new size: %d, %d\n", newWidth, newHeight);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );// a CGSize that has the size you want
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    //image is the original UIImage
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    
    return newImage;
}
```

Applying such scaling does indeed limit the total memory consumed by the thumbnails.